# Android screen sharing within app

Tags: android

I just want to share my android device screen with another android device. Kindly let me know if it's possible in android or not?
I googled it but was unable to get anything related to this topic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear what you want to do? Do you mean one app using two screens on two devices? What about two apps using two screens on two devices? Or you mean one large screen like on Desktop PCs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my opinion , this is possible because we have Team viewer app . Please refer these link , might be helpful to you

https://integrate.teamviewer.com/en/develop/screen-sharing-sdk/android-tutorial/